# How to move Uploaded file to another host in Php

Tags: apache, image-processing, phpmyadmin, ftp, image-uploading

Can anyone help me to implement how to move uploaded file from one server to another

I am not talking  about the move_uploaded_file() function.

for example,

> If the image is uploaded from http://example.com
>
> How can I move it to http://image.example.com

It is possible right? Not by sending another post or put request?

Comment: On subdomain or on different domain?

Comment: You can upload the file using php function to only same host means subdomains only.

Comment: Thanks guys i understood now
am now using the curl library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the Uploaded file, move it to a temporary location and push it then to any FTP-Acount you like.

```
$tempName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'upload');
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmpname"], $tempName);

$handle = fopen("ftp://user:password@example.com/somefile.txt", "w");
fwrite($handle, file_get_contents($uploadedFile));
fclose($handle);
unlink($tempName);
```

Actually you don't even need the part with the `move_uploaded_file`. It is totally sufficent to take the uploaded file and write it's content to the file opened with `fopen`. For more informations on opening URLs with `fopen`have a look at the [php-documentation](http://php.net/fopen). For more information on uploading files have a look at the [File-Upload-Section](http://php.net/file-upload) of the [PHP-Manual](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file)

**[Edit]** Added `file_get_contents` to the code-example

**[Edit]** Shorter Example

```
$handle = fopen("ftp://user:password@example.com/somefile.txt", "w");
fwrite($handle, file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmpname"]);
fclose($handle);
// As the uploaded file has not been moved from the temporary folder 
// it will be deleted from the server the moment the script is finished.
// So no cleaning up is required here.
```

Comment: never see something like this but apparently he just open a file but don't use the pass of the file but an url who is his ftp connexion

the end is classique usage of an opened file.

Nothing else to explain i think read some fopen doc you will find some explain ...